# Laravel pass accessor to vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

On one of my Laravel 5.4 models I've got multiple accessors. Like this:

```
public function getRevenueAttribute()
{
    return $this->calculate()->revenue($this->price, $this->amount);
}
```

The problem is that when I pass the model to my vue component:

```
<product :prp-product="{{json_encode($product)}}"></product>
```

`product.revenue` does not exists. Is there a way to achieve this? I don't want to calculate these things in vue again.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to add an `appends` Attribute to your model see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) for more info.

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['revenue'];
```